# In app billing implementation for ad removal android studio

Tags: android

I'm fairly new to android studio and I already have an app that I made myself with Admob implemented properly

I'm trying to add in app billing for ad removal and I have no idea how or where to start all the available tutorials are very confusing

I can really use some help or some sample code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Google Guide](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_integrate.html) to implement in app billing to your project